# Fade animation - not constant behavior Android

Tags: android, animation, fade

I want to make a Fade Out and In Animation every time I click a button.
I started to check only the fade out and on the first click it seems the Fade Out works just fine. But when I click again the animation fade from top to bottom, making it look bad and cut.

The Animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0"
       android:toAlpha="0.0"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
   android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

The Code:

```
Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(myActivity.this, R.anim.fade_out);
LinearLayout myBackground=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myBackground);
myBackground.setAnimation(fadeOut);
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: after you did setAnimation you need also to start the animation...  so myBackground.startAnimation

Comment: Can't believe it...I didn't realize I use Set and not Start! BTY I don't need the Set It works fine just with startAnimation . thank you :)

Comment: @Tomik I i'm not familiar with that, What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

**Make anim in following folder ris->anim->fade_anim.xml**
Add below xml

```
 <alpha
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
```

**Got to java class**

```
//make animation object
final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),    R.anim.bounce_anim);
    myAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);

//get View on which on you want to apply animation I am applying on imageView
mLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView).startAnimation(myAnim);
```